# Backup of Windows 10 (nvme) with DD

Tags: boot, partitioning, backup, dd

I am a complete newbie when it comes to using DD so please bear with me. I have a brand new laptop HP 250 G8, it has a NVME SSD disk in it. It comes with a preinstalled Windows 10.

I wanted to backup Windows using DD but it fails when I am telling it to copy entire disk.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0 | gzip -9 > /media/ubuntu/test1/win10.img.gz
dd: error reading '/dev/nvme0': Invalid argument
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0,000142093 s, 0,0 kB/s
```

Have not tried to backup one partition at a time because recreating the partitions would be a problem so I dont wanna go that way. Please help me?

Comment: Do you actually have a `/dev/nvme0` device? Maybe it's called differently. Use `lsblk` command to identify what disks and partitions do you have.

Comment: The `/dev/nvme0` reference seems incomplete. You should have two more letters after that, such as `n1` 

Comment: Beginners should not really use dd. Its nickname is data destroyer. Make double & triple check command is correct or you can lose all data. Also dd copies all empty space not not best way to backup. Better to use Windows tools or Linux tools that may work with any type of partitions. One of many tools. https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree

Answer (score -1):

As per comment, the device `/dev/nvme0n1` is indeed correct.

Comment: so it works when you enter `sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 | gzip -9 > /media/ubuntu/test1/win10.img.gz` then?